# What does 30 credit hours mean in case of dissertation?

Tags: thesis, masters

I have just got an offer letter from the University of Malaya for MSc in Software Engineering. It is a 42 credit hours course. 12 credits for courses. 30 credits for dissertation. I am confused with the latter part. What does 30 credits for dissertation mean? Does that mean that I would have to do class or being involved with the research in the lab for 30 hours every week?

Comment: In the US, a "credit" normally refers to 1 hr class time and around 2 hrs study outside of class. You wouldn't take 30 credits in a single semester. Usually the limit is 12-18 credits as a full-time student.

Answer (score 1):

The successful completion of the dissertation is awarded 30 credits. This means it has to show relevant effort, research, results - as per their marking scheme.

If the dissertation is not successful then you won’t be awarded the qualification, until they are satisfied - resubmission etc if that is allowed.

You will have to check their detail...

Comment: They haven't mentioned anything regarding the 30 credits. Does it mean that I would have to do class or being involved with the research in the lab for 30 hours every week?